# Create hotspot using CLI only - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, command-line, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

I saw many howto's for creating a hotspot in Ubuntu 14.04 (in AP mode) using system settings. They are perfect.

How do I create a hotspot **using only command line** however?

I tried messing around with eth0 and eth1 but I did not get anything at all.

(The same question has been asked some months ago, but it was not answered).

Comment: Have you looked at nmcli

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate with the question that was marked. I can answer the one that was  marked ... mine is different: command line only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use ap-hotspot to create hotspot on CLI

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8

sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

You are using Ubuntu 14.04 so there is a bug in **hostapd**.You need to downgrade it if you need to work on **ap-hotspot**

**Step:1**

```
sudo apt-get remove hostapd
```

**Step:2**

Copy and paste the command below into terminal that matches your OS type – check out via System Setting -> Details – and hit run to download, install, and hold the old version of hostapd.

While running the commands below, type in your user password in terminal when prompt.

If you use 64-bit system

```
 cd /tmp && wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa   /hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb && sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

If you use 32-bit system

```
cd /tmp && wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb && sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

**Step:3**

Configure your **ap-hotspot** if it installed

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

**Step:4**

To start your hotspot

```
 sudo ap-hotspot start
```

To stop your hotspot

```
 sudo ap-hotspot stop
```

Comment: Thank you. When entering sudo ap-hotspot configure in step 3 it tells me: 
"ap-hotspot command not found" . The previous steps seem to work well tough. Any hint please?